# Can anyone help me to understand what is the documented behavior of a_list * a_number in python?

Tags: python, list

If a_list is a simple list without any inner list, is it a simple concatenation of the list a_number times?

Comment: Make your question more understable by telling more and what's exactly your problem?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just try it out:

```
>>> [1,2,3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```